# How to separate Consecutive and Non consecutive number from a python list

Tags: python

Input:
lst = [101,102,103,104,120,131,132,133,134]

Expected output:
consecutive - [101,102,103,104,131,132,133,134]
non consecutive = [120]

```
def first_consecutive(lst):
    a = []
    for i,j in enumerate(lst,lst[0]):
        if i!=j:
            a.append(j)
    return a
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: in that code it return the first non consecutive number. But i need as my expected output as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You can just keep a list as you loop through the (sorted) numbers. When you encounter something that's consecutive, add it to the list. Otherwise put the values in the right place and redefine the list. Easier to show than explain:

```
l = [101,102,103,104, 120,131,132,133,134]

def partition_groups(l):
    out = [[], []]
    current = [l[0]]
    for n in l[1:]:
        if current[-1] + 1 == n:
            current.append(n)
        else:
            out[len(current) > 1].extend(current)
            current = [n]
    out[len(current) > 1].extend(current)
    return out
            
nonconsecutive, consecutive = partition_groups(l)      

print(nonconsecutive)
# [120]

print(consecutive)
# [101, 102, 103, 104, 131, 132, 133, 134]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Am trying with this list [737731, 737732, 737733, 737735, 737739, 737740, 737711, 737712, 737713]. While executing your code it result below: Non consecutive  [737735]
Consecutive: [737731, 737732, 737733, 737739, 737740, 737711, 737712, 737713]
Here i need 3 or more than 3 consecutive number  to be append in list

Comment: @AroJo how should someone know that if it's not in your question? Also, see that bit that says `len(current) > 1`? You can change that to suit your needs.

Comment: Am expecting a output like this is my list  [737731, 737732, 737733, 737735, 737739, 737740, 737711, 737712, 737713]. OUtput expected is :  [737731, 737732, 737733, 737735, 737711, 737712, 737713]. Here i need if the consecutive number are continuous three or more than 3. not less than 3 consecutive number.

Comment: How is `737735` consecutive to *anything* in your desired output.

Comment: Sorry that was data issue expected output:  [737731, 737732, 737733, 737711, 737712, 737713]

Comment: @AroJo as mention above you can just change the test, in this case: `out[len(current) > 2]` (in both places) will separate consecutive runs of three or more.

Comment: i did that change it works fine. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This? (assumes list is already sorted, if not just call `lst.sort()` first)

(Simply compare each element to its previous (if any) and next (if any) neighbour.)

```
consec = []
non_consec = []
L = len(lst)
for i in range(L):
    if i>0 and lst[i-1]==lst[i]-1 or i<L-1 and lst[i+1]==lst[i]+1:
        consec.append(lst[i])
    else:
        non_consec.append(lst[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
def sort_list(list):
    sorted_list = []
    non_consecutive_list = []

    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] + 1 in list or list[i] - 1 in list:
           sorted_list.append(list[i])
        
        else:
           non_consecutive_list.append(list[i])

    return sorted_list, non_consecutive_list

num_list = [101,102,103,104,120,131,132,133,134]

sorted_list, non_consecutive_list = sort_list(num_list)
print(sorted_list, non_consecutive_list)
```